# exec command in tcl with file argument

Tags: tcl

I am new in tcl.

I want to ask the question about tcl exec command. I want to execute the command through `exec` with `-file` arguments. for example

```
exec myprogram -tcl -file [file_name.tcl] -nogui
```

I am writing this code in tcl_file and trying to execute the tcl code through `tclsh tcl_file.tcl` , but due to wrong arguments I could not able to pass file_name.
advance thanks

Comment: my tcl_file contain only this command                                                      [exec myprogram -tcl -file "file_name.tcl" .]

Comment: What was the _exact_ error message?

Comment: invalid command name "file_name.tcl"
    while executing
"file_name.tcl"
    invoked from within
"exec myprogram -tcl -file [file_name.tcl] -nogui "
    (file "tcl_file" line 3)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you've got is that `[` and `]` are used in Tcl to surround commands for substituting. It's making the filename be interpreted as a (really quite unusual) Tcl command name.

You're probably OK doing just this:

```
exec myprogram -tcl -file file_name.tcl -nogui
```

Without the `[`…`]`. However, if the program that you're calling needs the square brackets, you'll have to backslash-quote them:

```
exec myprogram -tcl -file \[file_name.tcl\] -nogui
```

That's pretty unlikely. Prefer the first option.